# How can I group a foreach loop's output?

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, foreach

I'm working with Bootstrap's grid and I'm iterating through an array of names. The problem is that I don't know how to place X amount of results per parent div.

$names = mysql result containing 9 names.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <?php
    foreach ($names as $name){
     echo '
      <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3">
        <p>Customer name:'.$name.'</p>
      </div>';  
     }  
   </div>
</div>
```

That would output this 9 times.

```
<div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3">
  <p> Customer name: Foo </p>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3">
  <p> Customer name: bob </p>
</div> 
<div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3">
  <p> Customer name: jim </p>
</div> 
<div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3">
  <p> Customer name: dave </p>
</div> 
<div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3">
  <p> Customer name: lucy </p>
</div> 
<div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3">
  <p> Customer name: sarah </p>
</div> 
<div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3">
  <p> Customer name: geoff </p>
</div> 
<div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3">
  <p> Customer name: matt </p>
</div> 
<div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3">
  <p> Customer name: alex </p>
</div>
```

How can I make it output 3 column divs per `.row` like this?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3">
      <p> Customer name: Foo </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3">
      <p> Customer name: bob </p>
    </div> 
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3">
      <p> Customer name: jim </p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3">
      <p> Customer name: dave </p>
    </div> 
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3">
      <p> Customer name: lucy </p>
    </div> 
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3">
      <p> Customer name: sarah </p>
    </div> 
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3">
      <p> Customer name: geoff </p>
    </div> 
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3">
      <p> Customer name: matt </p>
    </div> 
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3">
      <p> Customer name: alex </p>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: I see in a subsequent question you are using my answer as the example for that one, if you feel your question is answered, feel free to mark as such.

Comment: My apologies, I forgot to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to think about an [array_chunk()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) which would take care of uneven number of names:

```
$names  =   array('Dave','Frank','Sarah','Dan','Andrew','Jessica','Alena','Debbie','Jeff');
$split  =   array_chunk($names,3);
?>
<div class="container">
<?php
    foreach ($split as $group){
        echo '
    <div class="row">';
        foreach ($group as $name){
            echo '
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3">
            <p>Customer name:'.$name.'</p>
        </div>';
        }
        echo '
    </div>';
    } 
?>
</div>
```

Comment: I have used both modulus and auto-incremental solutions before, both are good, but I personally use `array_chunk()` because I find it straight-forward. Thanks for the *vote of confidence* so-to-speak! Cheers.

Comment: I like it, nice solution

Answer (score 1):

Use an explicit variable in your loop with a condition based on the variable value. For instance:

```
$i = 0;

foreach ($names as $name)
{
    if($i == 0)
    {
        echo '<div class="row">';
    }

    echo
    '<div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3">
        <p>Customer name:'.$name.'</p>
    </div>';
    $i++;

    if($i == 2)
    {
        echo '</div>';
        $i = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to remove the `<div class="row">` and let them stack. If you make sure to set all the options, say `<div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">` then they should stack accordingly. Unless there is a separate need to have them broken into exact rows. This is also a quick thought of the head.. not tested, and maybe not what is needed.

Also, there is this bit too

```
if (($counter + 1) % 3 == 0) {
  //do code here
}
```

or

```
if ($counter % 3 == 0) {
      //do code 
    }
$counter++;
```